# What is the legitimate reason to have "disable remote input" available at all on TeamViewer?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, teamviewer

I've been watching some (Jim Browning) videos where the video shows the scammer's perspective of a scam, and regularly the scammers use the "Disable remote input" and "Show black screen" options on TeamViewer. Using that, they can do some nasty stuff on the victim's computer, and optionally have the victim watch as all of their files get deleted, for example.

So that made me wonder: what is the actual legitimate use case where disabling remote input is actually necessary? I'd assume the intended purpose is when someone is helping out a relative (or customer for that matter), and then they keep moving their mouse, which can be annoying. I can imagine that was the use case this was invented for. But if that is the only type of use case, I can't imagine anyone in their right mind would consider that enough reason to build that into the product.

I've made some software myself where the power given to users via that software could perhaps do more harm than good (in my case: automated editing software for Wikipedia), and one of my first considerations for new features is always: Can this do more harm than good? Will this be used by malicious users for vandalism? Because of that, I really can't imagine "disable remote input" being implemented and anyone answering "no" to similar questions as mine for TeamViewer's case.

TeamViewer in itself, without being able to prevent the *computer's owner* from interacting with *their own machine*, is already powerful enough, because it can allow people with malicious intent to do some really nasty stuff to people's computers, for example pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> and <kbd>enter</kbd> in quick succession. Because of that, my question is this: does anyone know what the intended use case for these features is? Because so far, I'm getting convinced by those videos that TeamViewer is worse than a virus, in some cases.

**PS:** I know this is a relatively subjective question, but it does still seem to meet most of the criteria listed at the bottom of [this page](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask), I believe.

Comment: They are preventing your ability to control their machine.

Comment: The way I'm understanding is that "disable remote input" disables the input from the user on their own pc. I've tried searching around on Google and I found no sources that stated otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both features "Disable remote input" and "Show black screen" both makes sense if you use TeamViewer as a Remote Desktop replacement for working remotely on a server that has keyboard, mouse and monitor attached but should not be used while you are connected via TeamViewer by any local user.

Hence in this scenario either the local user or the remote user should be able to use the machine.

In addition the "Show black screen" feature may be useful in case a remote assistant user has to enter sensitive information such as a password in a shell that would be otherwise visible to the user.

Answer (score 1):

These are for security reasons when remotely managing / using a machine that is not in use by a person (like remoting into a server or workstation that is used to do work remotely).

If the person remoting in pulled up sensitive information, if someone was there and a monitor was connected, they could see it.  Or if they didn't check to disable remote input, then someone bad who happened to be there could click on stuff you wouldn't want them to.